# Need a controller named "directory" in codeigniter

Tags: php, url, codeigniter

I need my controller to be name "directory" so I can have urls for my business directory page like `"mysite.com/directory"`.
But the problem is that "directory" is a predefined php class, so I cannot declare it again. It gives error

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class
>   Directory in
>   C:\wamp\www\Logistica\system\application\controllers\directory.php
>   on line 8

Is there a way I can rename my class and controller to something else and still have the "directory" in URL ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [CodeIgniter routing](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)

In your case you'll want a route like:

> $route['directory'] = "DirectoryImplementationClass";

Comment: I am already using CI URL identifier so my routes class is a little modified already. My urls are "mysite.com/en/directory" , here is my routes code :
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['(\w{2})/(.*)'] = '$2';
$route['(\w{2})'] = $route['default_controller'];
$route['\w{2}/directory'] = "Dirclass";

But the above is still not matching the url for me. It is giving me 404 error on page.

Comment: It's been a while since I've used CI but if I remember correctly the order of the rules is important. The first matching route will be run, not the most specific one. So if  $route['(\w{2})/(.*)'] = '$2' is before $route['\w{2}/directory'] = "Dirclass"; in your route.php file then it will be looking for the directory.php class and the second route will never be executed.

Answer (score 1):

you can use .htaccess to change the URL.
that means your name is something other than directory
then you can use Rewrite rules to change the name in URL

reference:
[htaccess in codeigniter](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Dreamhost_.htaccess/)